# Making a Web.Config File support REST and able to upload an image

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, azure

I am making a WCF service that will run on Azure. 
It deals with REST service to send and receive XML data, but in this application you can also upload Images. 
Now i don't want to have to run two WCF services one for the REST and one for the Image upload but i cant get the Web.Config file to work with one of them changed. 
Here is both of them.

## This one is Photo web.config file

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <!--  To collect diagnostic traces, uncomment the section below or merge with existing system.diagnostics section.
            To persist the traces to storage, update the DiagnosticsConnectionString setting with your storage credentials.
            To avoid performance degradation, remember to disable tracing on production deployments.
      <system.diagnostics>     
        <sharedListeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage" type="WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, WCFServiceWebRole1"/>
        </sharedListeners>
        <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
              <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
            </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
            <listeners>
              <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources> 
       </system.diagnostics> -->
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
          <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
              name="AzureDiagnostics">
              <filter type="" />
            </add>
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </system.diagnostics>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="8092" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
              <security mode="None"></security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <services>
          <service name="WCFServiceWebRole1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="myBehaviour">
            <endpoint binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="myBehaviour">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpGetUrl="" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
        -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
      </system.webServer>
    </configuration>
```

## The other one is the REST one that sends and receives data *The Connection Strings have been Removed*

```
<!-- language: lang-xml -->

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <!--  To collect diagnostic traces, uncomment the section below or merge with existing system.diagnostics section.
            To persist the traces to storage, update the DiagnosticsConnectionString setting with your storage credentials.
            To avoid performance degradation, remember to disable tracing on production deployments.
      <system.diagnostics>     
        <sharedListeners>
          <add name="AzureLocalStorage" type="WCFServiceWebRole1.AzureLocalStorageTraceListener, WCFServiceWebRole1"/>
        </sharedListeners>
        <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Verbose, ActivityTracing">
            <listeners>
              <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
            </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging" switchValue="Verbose">
            <listeners>
              <add name="AzureLocalStorage"/>
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources> 
       </system.diagnostics> -->
      <system.diagnostics>
        <trace>
          <listeners>
            <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=2.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics"></add>
          </listeners>
        </trace>
      </system.diagnostics>
      <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">
          <assemblies>
            <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
          </assemblies>
        </compilation>
      </system.web>
      <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
          <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
          <service name="WCFServiceWebRole1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehaviour">
            <!-- Add the following endpoint.  -->
            <!-- Note: your service must have an http base address to add this endpoint. -->
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
            <endpoint binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WCFServiceWebRole1.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web" />
          </service>
        </services>
        <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="ServiceBehaviour">
              <!-- Add the following element to your service behavior configuration. -->
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
          <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="web">
              <webHttp />
            </behavior>
          </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
      </system.serviceModel>
      <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <!--
            To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
            Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
        -->
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
      </system.webServer>
      <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ThemeParkData_Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/ThemeParkData.csdl|res://*/ThemeParkData.ssdl|res://*/ThemeParkData.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=REMOVED.windows.net;initial catalog=ThemeParkData;persist security info=True;user id=REMOVED;password=REMOVED;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
        <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="REMOVED" />
      </connectionStrings>
      <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
          <parameters>
            <parameter value="v12.0" />
          </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
      </entityFramework>
    </configuration>
```

What i need is both of them in one config file for them to work together. if that is possible.
Now sadly i have only been using this file for a short period of time so don't fully understand it. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can have the same service configured for multiple endpoints and behaviors.

The config below allows a service to be accessed using soad/xml/json and a custom upload routing with no internal changes to the service implementation. Sorry if this does not answer you project specific question but it should give you an idea of how modify one service with different behaviors and or endpoints.

This service can be accessed in the following ways:

```
http:\\MyService1.svc\json\SomeMethod <--Input and output is serialized as json
http:\\MyService1.svc\xml\SomeMethod <--Input and output is serialized as pox
http:\\MyService1.svc\upload\SomeMethod <--Input and output is customized
http:\\MyService1.svc\SomeMethod <--accessed as soap
```

**Config**

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WebxmlHttp">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
        <binding name="WebjsonHttp">
          <security mode="None"/>
        </binding>
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="wsHttpEndpointBinding" receiveTimeout="00:30:00" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="SecureServiceBehavior" name="MyServices.ServiceImplementation.MyService1">
        <clear/>
        <endpoint address="xml" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebxmlHttp" behaviorConfiguration="xmlBehavior" name="webXMLHttpBinding" contract="MySevices.ServiceContracts.IMyService1"/>
        <endpoint address="json" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WebjsonHttp" behaviorConfiguration="jsonBehavior" name="webJSONHttpBinding" contract="MyServices.ServiceContracts.IMyService1"/>
        <endpoint address="upload" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="wsHttpBinding"  name="updloadHttpBinding" contract="MySevices.ServiceContracts.IMyService1"/>

      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="jsonBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="xmlBehavior">
          <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Xml"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SecureServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceTimeouts transactionTimeout="00:03:00"/>
          <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="10" maxConcurrentSessions="10" maxConcurrentInstances="10"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
```

Comment: Thank you, I belive that should help,
Its also helped me understand how that file works a lot better to me.